# Mocking module global variable while import

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, unit-testing, flask

I am writing unit tests for the api, which connects to MongoDB. In my API module it looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from MyApp import MongoData

api = Flask(__name__)
DB_CONN = MongoData()

@api.route('/bla', methods=['GET'])
def alive():
    return jsonify({'response': true})
```

I have a problem while importing this module in my unittest. I want to mock collection from MongoData() with special mock class, which uses mongomock. The problem is that I cannot mock DB_CONN while importing in tests:

```
from MyApp import api
```

I was trying to do this with mock:

```
DB_CONN = MockMongoData()
with mock.patch('MyApp.api.DB_CONN', DB_CONN):
    from MyApp import api
```

but it still tries to connect to the database as specified in the config file.

Any advice how to mock DB_CONN from MyApp.api module?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This will work:

```
import sys    
from MyApp import MongoData, MockMongoData
sys.modules['MyApp'].MongoData = MockMongoData
from MyApp import api
```

But is there a better (more pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: You're mocking the object `MyApp.api.DB_CONN` and importing it together. Try just mock, not importing

Comment: I am importing everything from MyApp.api, together with methods I want to test, so mocking instead of importing won't work. Methods depend on the connection to the database, hence I have to mock DB_CONN 'inside' the module I am importing.

Answer (score 1):

Import the module first, then monkeypatch its members:

```
DB_CONN = MockMongoData()

from MyApp import api

with mock.patch('MyApp.api.DB_CONN', DB_CONN):
    api.run()
```

Comment: The problem is that interpreter creates instance of MongoData class while `from MyApp import api` is executed.

Comment: The instance will be shadowed, so it will just be idle and do nothing. If you don't want the instance to be created at all, move it in the `__name__ == "__main__"` block or whatever you use to start the server.